# Lightweight CLI Website Uptime Monitoring

Tags: open-source, command-line, monitoring, network-monitor

I'm looking for a very lightweight, open-source, linux CLI tool for monitoring the uptime of a set of websites.

I do *not* want a tool that includes a web server. I'm thinking of something like [mon](https://softpanorama.org/Admin/Monitoring/mon.shtml), but where it records the state of each run in some database (eg RRDTool, whisper, etc).

I should be able to give this tool

1. A simple config file listing all the `https://xyz` URLs of websites to check (and maybe what status code is expected)
2. A path to a database file

...and then tell it to run. When the run is finished, it should update the database.

At any time, I should be able to query this tool for the uptime of a specific URL, and it should tell me the website's uptime (as a percent).

Is there any lightweight, open-source, CLI, stateful uptime monitoring tool?

Comment: See also RRDTool https://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/

Comment: See also MRTG https://oss.oetiker.ch/mrtg/

Comment: See also mon https://sourceforge.net/projects/mon/

Comment: See also Monitorix https://www.monitorix.org/

Comment: See also Graphite https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: See also Alerta https://github.com/alerta/python-alerta-client